# Typeerror with filename

Tags: python, excel

I'm getting the following error with line 18 -  "TypeError: Open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filename2'".   Can someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?Thanks in advance

```
import os
import win32com.client

path = r'XXX'
pathmaster = r'XXX\MyFile.xlsx'
filename=pathmaster

xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = False

wbmaster = xl.Workbooks.Open(filename)

sheets = os.listdir(path)

for sheet in sheets:
    print(sheet)
    wb1=xl.Workbooks.Open(filename2 = os.path.join(path,sheet))

    ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Val")
    ws1.Name=sheet[:4]

    ws1.Copy(Before=wbmaster.Worksheets(1))
    wb1.Close(True)

wbmaster.Close(SaveChanges=True)
```

Comment: Why do you think `filename2` is the correct parameter name?

Comment: Why are you using `win32com` if you have `openpyxl` available?

Comment: filename2 was a typo, (should just read as filename) but that still yields the same error.  as for win32com versus openpyxl, i'm relatively new to this so I'm learning as I am going along.  since the files are xlsm files, i thought openpyxl was appropriate to use